# Why is router.navigate() returning false?

Tags: angular, angular7

I have two lazy loading modules (site, and gtd), that both contain a handful of routes. I want all child routes in the gtd component (paths with 'app/*') to be protected by the AuthGuard. I'm using Auth0 for authentication.

But for whatever reason, after authenticating I try and call `this.router.navigate('/app')` and it always resolves to `false`. I've tried it both with & without the `AuthGuard` and it results in the same behavior. So I don't think it's an issue with the route guard. But just in case, I've included it here.

There are no error messages or anything of the sort.

*Why is it failing to route?*

Here are my routes:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuardService as AuthGuard } from './core/auth/auth-guard.service';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'site', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'site', loadChildren: './site/site.module#SiteModule' },
  { path: 'app', loadChildren: './gtd/gtd.module#GtdModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Here is the AuthGuard:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(public auth: AuthService, public router: Router) { }

  canActivate(): boolean {
    if (!this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      console.log('Not authenticated')
      this.router.navigate(['']);
      return false;
    }
    console.log('Authentication guard satisfied.')
    return true;
  }
}
```

Here is the Authentication Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import * as auth0 from 'auth0-js';
import { LogService } from '../util/log.service';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  private loginRedirect = environment.auth0.loginRedirectUrl;
  private logoutRedirectTo = environment.auth0.logoutRedirectTo;
  private clientID = environment.auth0.clientID;
  private domain = environment.auth0.domain;

  private _idToken: string;
  private _accessToken: string;
  private _expiresAt: number;

  userProfile: any;

  auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
    clientID: this.clientID,
    domain: this.domain,
    responseType: 'token id_token',
    redirectUri: this.loginRedirect,
    scope: 'openid'
  });


  constructor(public router: Router, public logger: LogService, public location: Location) {
    this._idToken = '';
    this._accessToken = '';
    this._expiresAt = 0;
   }

   get accessToken(): string {
     return this.accessToken;
   }

   get idToken(): string {
    return this._idToken;
   }


   public getProfile(cb): void {
     if (!this._accessToken) {
       const errMsg = 'Access Token must exist to fetch profile';
       this.logger.error(errMsg);
       throw new Error(errMsg);
     }

     const self = this;
     this.auth0.client.userInfo(this._accessToken, (err, profile) => {
       if (profile) {
         self.userProfile = profile;
       }

       cb(err, profile);
     });
   }

   login(): void {
     this.auth0.authorize();
   }

   public handleAuthentication(): void {
     this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
       if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
          window.location.hash = '';
          this.localLogin(authResult);
          this.logger.log('Authentication Result:', authResult);
          this.router.navigate(['/app']);
       } else if (err) {
         this.router.navigate(['/home']);
         console.log(err);
       }
     });
   }

   private localLogin(authResult): void {
     // Set isLoggedIn flag in localStorage
     localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', 'true');
     // Set the time that the access token will expire at
     const expiresAt = (authResult.expiresAt * 1000) + new Date().getTime();
     this._accessToken = authResult.accessToken;
     this._idToken = authResult.idToken;
     this._expiresAt = expiresAt;
   }


   public renewTokens(): void {
     this.auth0.checkSession({}, (err, authResult) => {
       if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
         this.localLogin(authResult);
       } else if (err) {
         alert (`Could not get a new token (${err.error}: ${err.error_description}).`);
         this.logout();
       }
     });
   }

   public logout(): void {
     // Remove tokens and expiry time
     this._accessToken = '';
     this._idToken = '';
     this._expiresAt = 0;
     // Remove isLoggedIn flag from localStorage
     localStorage.removeItem('isLoggedIn');

     // Go back to the home route
      window.location.href = `http://${this.domain}/logout?returnTo=${this.logoutRedirectTo}`;

     this.router.navigate(['/']);

     this.logger.info('Access token', this._accessToken);
     this.logger.info('IdToken', this._idToken);
   }

   public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
     // Check whether the current time is past the access token's expiry time
     return new Date().getTime() < this._expiresAt;
   }
}
```

I'm calling handleAuthentication in the component loaded in the login callback url:
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { AuthService } from 'src/app/core/auth/auth.service';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-callback',
  templateUrl: './login-callback.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-callback.component.scss']
})
export class LoginCallbackComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.authService.isAuthenticated())
    this.authService.handleAuthentication();
  }

}
```

I can't figure out why, but `this.router.navigate()` resolves to `false`.

Comment: Have you tried turning on route tracing? That sometimes helps to see what may be going wrong: ` { enableTracing: true }` on the `.forRoot([])` method.

Comment: This was very helpful. I found that the navigation was gettting canceled due to the navigationTrigger: "hashchange" that was triggered by the line `window.location.hash = ''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was happening was that the line `window.location.hash = ''` was triggering another navigation event. This event interrupted and canceled the navigation to `/app`.

Clearing the hash wasn't even necessary because I was immediately routing using an absolute route.

Comment: Maybe it will help someone, I've noticed that if you trigger two navigations in a row (by mistake call navigate twice) - navigations will cancel each other!

Answer (score 2):

You are calling

```
this.router.navigate(['app']);
```

You need to call

```
this.router.navigate(['/app']);
```

Hopefully this fixes it!

Comment: This is correct. I'll update my question. I should've added to the question that I had tried it both as a relative and absolute path, and it still failed to navigate.